# Adding multiple lines to body of SMTP email VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I can use this code to send an email on my Exchange server

```
Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
        Dim mail As New MailMessage
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential()
        SmtpServer.Port = 25
        SmtpServer.Host = "email.host.com"
        mail = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail@email.com")
        mail.To.Add("otheremail@email.com")
        mail.Subject = "Equipment Request"
        mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from me" 


        SmtpServer.Send(mail)

    catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

But how can I add multiple lines to the body?

Comment: What's wrong in preparing a string message with multiple lines and add this all together to the body property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just treat it like a normal text object where you can use `Environment.NewLine` or `vbNewLine` between sentences.

`StringBuilder` is useful here:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine("Line One")
sb.AppendLine("Line Two")

mail.Body = sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 4):

I would create a variable for your body and then add that to the mail.Body so it would look something like this.

```
Try
    Dim strBody as string = ""
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
    Dim mail As New MailMessage
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential()
    SmtpServer.Port = 25
    SmtpServer.Host = "email.host.com"
    mail = New MailMessage
    mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail@email.com")
    mail.To.Add("otheremail@email.com")
    mail.Subject = "Equipment Request"
    strBody = "This is for testing SMTP mail from me" & vbCrLf
    strBody += "line 2" & vbCrLf
    mail.Body = strBody

    SmtpServer.Send(mail)

catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

That will append the line breaks and you should have each line on it's own in the email.

Answer (score 4):

If the body of your message needs to be in HTML format, add the `<br>` tags right in your String. `vbCrLf` and `StringBuilder` don't work if the body is in HTML format.

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
mail.Body = "First Line<br>"
mail.Body += "Second Line<br>"
mail.Body += "Third Line"
```

If it is not in HTML format, the other answers here appear to be good.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
Dim myMessage as String = "This is for testing SMTP mail from me" + Environment.NewLine
myMessage = myMessage + "Line1" + Environment.NewLine
```

then

```
mail.Body = myMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

try the `system.environment.newline` in the the string ... should work

Answer (score 0):

What it works for me is using 
 in the string..

```
strBody = "This is for testing SMTP mail from me<BR> line 2"
```