# Email line breaks not working

Tags: vb.net, email, line-breaks

I am trying to force line breaks inside the body of my automatic email.

I have referenced many examples, such as ["Adding multiple lines to body of SMTP email VB.NET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283400/adding-multiple-lines-to-body-of-smtp-email-vb-net).

I've tried many different ways to make line breaks:

1. StringBuilder.AppendLine

   ```
   Dim sb As New StringBuilder
   sb.AppendLine("For security purposes, only the password will be provided within this email.")
   sb.AppendLine("Thank you and have a wonderful day.")
   ```
2. System.Environment.NewLine

   ```
   strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. " & System.Environment.NewLine
   strbody = strbody & "Password: " & Dsa.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2) & System.Environment.NewLine & System.Environment.NewLine
   ```
3. vbNewLine

   ```
   strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. " &  vbNewLine
   ```
4. vbCrLf

   ```
   strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. " & vbCrLf
   ```
5. Environment.NewLine

   ```
   strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. " & Environment.NewLine
   ```

and so on, but every time I receive the email there are no line breaks.

Is there any other versions I can test?

```
Dim strbody As String

Try

    Dim strTo As String

     strbody = ""
    strbody = strbody & "Thank you for contacting us to gain account access. " & vbNewLine
    strbody = strbody & "You requested your password for the Applicaton registration site. " & vbNewLine
    strbody = strbody & "For security purposes, only the password will be provided within this email. " & vbNewLine
    strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. " & vbNewLine
    strbody = strbody & "Password: " & Dsa.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2) & System.Environment.NewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    strbody = strbody & "If you didn't request your password, please notify from@location.com of your concern "


    strTo = Dsa.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    Dim msg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from@we-location.com", strTo, "Retrive Your Password", strbody)

    Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient


    msg.IsBodyHtml = True
    smtp.Host = "mailhost.location.com"
    smtp.Send(msg)

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key line of code here is this:

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Since you are sending an HTML email you must use HTML markup to create line breaks.

```
strbody = strbody & "Thank you for contacting us to gain account access. <br><br>"
```

Comment: Wow. I forgot that I had that line of coding since I was using one of my old examples in another program. Thanks it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Are you working with a html template?

Try with

```
strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. <br>"
```

or \n

```
strbody = strbody & "Thank you and have a wonderful day. \n"
```

Comment: I forgot that I had enforced html in my coding. So yes the <br> works; however, I read NoAlias's first. I really appreciate your help too!

Comment: I don't think \n is relevant here, so I think this should be the accepted answer if that part is removed as it was first to be posted

Comment: @MattWilko I do agree that since this was first posted it should be accepted as the answer; however, when I refreshed the page NoAlias's post showed before his so that is why I accepted it first and when he listed the `msg.IsBodyHTML` text to show me what made my coding html really helped me too.